# Complicated Average calculation in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

sql server 2008

I have a table where i am calculating percentage of data available in value column against all the column.

now i am trying to calculate avg  percentage of data available in value column

but the challenge is while calculating **over all avg** 
i need to exclude these type of column 
for example

if DENTAL is NULL and DENTAL_VALUE IS NULL i should not consider while calculating average.

but if DENTAL is NOT NULL and DENTAL_VALUE IS NULL those will be include in computation.

The below script gives me avg of each column,

may anyone please help me how can i calculate **OVERALL average** for above scenario.

SO in this case while calculating overall average i have to exclude dental and dental_value but don't exclude nephro.

Table

```
DECLARE @PHARMA TABLE
(
MRN VARCHAR (30),
department VARCHAR (30),
optical VARCHAR (30),
optical_value VARCHAR (30), 
dermo VARCHAR (30),
dermo_value VARCHAR (30),
Neuro VARCHAR (30),
Neuro_value VARCHAR (30),
DENTAL VARCHAR (30),
DENTAL_VALUE VARCHAR (30)
   Nephro VARCHAR (30),
    Nephro_VALUE VARCHAR (30)
)

Insert @PHARMA

SELECT 'BSE23098', 'Clinic', 'Willmar','10', 'Betamethasone' ,'20', 'neurobion', NULL,NULL,NULL,'TYPE-A',NULL UNION ALL

SELECT 'ZSE23098', 'Clinic', 'AUROBRIME','10', 'adapalene' ,'20', 'Blong', NULL,NULL,NULL,'TYPE-B',NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZSE23098', 'Clinic', 'VOZOLE', NULL, 'SURFRAZ', '30' ,'Evion', '63' ,NULL,NULL,'TYPE-C',NULL
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(optical_not_NULL * 100.0 / NULLIF((optical_NULL + optical_not_NULL), 0) AS decimal(5, 2)) AS optical_fill_rate,
    CAST(dermo_not_NULL * 100.0 / NULLIF((dermo_NULL + dermo_not_NULL), 0) AS decimal(5, 2)) AS dermo_fill_rate,
    CAST(dental_not_NULL * 100.0 / NULLIF((dental_NULL + dental_not_NULL), 0) AS decimal(5, 2)) AS dental_fill_rate,
    CAST(neuro_not_NULL * 100.0 / NULLIF((neuro_NULL + neuro_not_NULL), 0) AS decimal(5, 2)) AS neuro_fill_rate
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN optical_value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS optical_NULL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN optical_value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS optical_not_NULL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dermo_value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dermo_NULL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dermo_value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS dermo_not_NULL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN neuro_value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS neuro_NULL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN neuro_value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS neuro_not_NULL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dental_value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dental_NULL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dental_value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS dental_not_NULL

    FROM @PHARMA
) AS derived
```

Comment: what is the expected result like ?

Comment: @Squirrel: result like : Overall Avg
50%

Comment: the 50% is for which value ? How did you derived to that 50% ?

Comment: @Squirrel: i tried something like query above.

this gives me each column fill rate, 
but my problem is i want to exclude column when 

DENTAL IS NULL AND DENTAL_VALUE is also NULL

but when column like
 Nephro is not null and Nephro_VALUE is null, i need to retain this.

along with this i need to have one more extra column as overall avg.

Comment: @Squirrel: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can simplify to

```
SELECT  CAST (COUNT (CASE WHEN optical is not null 
                          THEN optical_value END)
              * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS decimal(5,2) ) as optical_fill_rate
FROM    @PHARMA
```

Comment: Is it possible when Dental is null and DENTAL_value is null then DENTAL_fill_rate should be 100 instead of 0