# Average Calculation in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate over-all average of fill rate for value column,
but only when its description is not null, if description and value is null, then it should exclude from average calculation.

```
DECLARE @MASTER TABLE
(
    PRODUCT    VARCHAR (50),
    Desc1      VARCHAR (50),
    Desc1Value VARCHAR (50),    
    Desc2      VARCHAR (50),
    Desc2Value VARCHAR (50), 
    Desc3      VARCHAR (50),
    Desc3Value VARCHAR (50),
    Desc4      VARCHAR (50),
    Desc4Value VARCHAR (50),
    Desc5      VARCHAR (50),
    Desc5Value VARCHAR (50),
    Desc6      VARCHAR (50),
    Desc6Value VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @MASTER
    SELECT 
        'AMPLIFIER', 'Color', 'Black', 'Material',  
        'Blended TPO', 'Edge Type', 'Raised', 
        'Surface Type', 'Non-Skid', 'Coverage', NULL,   
        NULL, NULL 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        'AMPLIFIER', 'Color', 'Black', 'Material', 'Blended TPO',   
        'Edge Type', 'Raised', 'Surface Type', 'Non-Skid',  
        'Coverage', NULL, NULL, NULL 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        'RECTIFIER', 'Style', 'Film Kit', 'Color', 'Clear', 
        'Material', 'Urethane', 'Quantity', NULL, NULL, NULL,   
        NULL, NULL 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        'RECTIFIER', 'Style', 'Film Kit', 'Color', 'Clear', 
        'Material', 'Urethane', 'Quantity', NULL, NULL, NULL,   
        NULL, NULL 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        'Diode', 'Rating', '6 Ampere', 'Quantity', 'Pack Of 12',    
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

Expected output:

```
Overall_fillrate:- 68.33%
```

May anyone please help me, i tried multiple way but couldn't achieve it.

Thanks,

Comment: And how do you get `68.33%` from that data? (Also, your database structure is horrid! Why? Just something as simple as "find me all the products I have which are coloured black" is hard to write)

Comment: This post makes no sense to me.

Comment: Simplify example, have fewer columns.

Comment: Also - what about your [identical question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150433/complicated-average-calculation-in-sql-server-2008) didnt answer this question?

Comment: no wonder this sounds familiar. . . .

Comment: @Squirrel: Thanks . what i am trying is something like
average Fill rate = sum (descvalue)/sum(desc), excluding NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this ?

```
select  (COUNT(CASE WHEN Desc1 is not null then Desc1Value end)
    + COUNT(CASE WHEN Desc2 is not null then Desc2Value end)
    + COUNT(CASE WHEN Desc3 is not null then Desc3Value end)
    + COUNT(CASE WHEN Desc4 is not null then Desc4Value end)
    + COUNT(CASE WHEN Desc5 is not null then Desc5Value end)
    + COUNT(CASE WHEN Desc6 is not null then Desc6Value end))
    * 100.0
    / ( 6 * COUNT(*))
from    @MASTER
```